# make text fully contained in a bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown button, and this drop down ontains many elements that has differente font-sizes :

```
<ul id="tailles" class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a style="font-size: 8px;">Petite (8px)</a></li>
  <li><a style="font-size: 10px;">Petite (10px)</a></li>
  <li><a style="font-size: 12px;">Petite (12px)</a></li>
  <li><a style="font-size: 14px;">Normale (14px)</a></li>
  <li><a style="font-size: 18px;">Grande (18px)</a></li>
  <li><a style="font-size: 24px;">Grande (24px)</a></li>
  <li><a style="font-size: 36px;">Grande (36px)</a></li>
</ul>
```

but the dropdown-menu looks ugly, the text isn't fully contained in it's container, I tried to change the height for each  and it didn't worked out.

How can I solve this ?

## Edit :

This is how it looks :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the height of the `<li>` element. Try setting its' height to at least the same as font-size and add some pixels for margin ...for example:
`<li style="height:22px"><a style="font-size: 18px;">Grande (18px)</a></li>`
`<li style="height:24px"><a style="font-size: 20px;">Grande (20px)</a></li>`
...etc

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a css padding on the li element, like padding: 3px 0px; or you need to set another line-height with css for each li element.

And try setting the font size in the li element, not in the a tag